# ActiveMQ Redelivery Policy - How does it work?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Can anyone please explain how ActiveMQ Redelivery Policy actually works?
Is it working on the client or server side?

Let's say I have a redelivery policy to redeliver a message for up to 10 minutes with an interval of 30 minutes between each attempt, then where exactly the failed message lives?

Assuming that the message failed now and it got to be redelivered after 30 minutes, then where does the message live?

I see that the same consumer gets the message after 30 minutes.

I am wondering where ActiveMQ stores this message for 30 minutes.

If I shut down the consumer or my consumer has crashed, will I be able to recover the message after 30 minutes?

I went thru these ActiveMQ pages for Redelivery Policy and I didn't find any info:

http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html
http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two types of redelivery. The typical one is the redelivery policy you bind to the ConnectionFactory client side. The broker is not aware of the redelivery in this setup since it's handled by the client, and the message is actually on the client waiting for redelivery. However, since the message is not committed (or Acknowledged) by the client, the broker won't delete it. So, if the message is up for redelivery in 30 minutes, but the client application goes down after 10 minutes, the message will be back visible on the broker.

There is also broker side redelivery via a plugin. In that case, the broker handles redelivery. There are pros and cons, specifically that you can't control it from client code - but the broker admin can control it. This means broker redelivery can redeliver to a different consumer while client side redelivery cannot.

Read more about broker redelivery at the bottom of this page:
http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tested the case when client crashes and I found that the test message was not lost.

Comment: Can the message be really redelivered to a different consumer when using broker redelivery plugin? Asking because couldn't find a reference saying this.

Comment: @SumitJain You dont deliver messages to consumers at all. Consumers consume messages from queues. If your consumer is gone and a new consumer gets atteched to the queue, yes, the message will be there unless it was expired or max number of redeliveries is reached so then is moved to DLQ

Comment: @Rafael That is wrong, broker pushes messages to consumers in activemq, see http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html It says "To make efficient use of network resources the broker utilizes a ‘push’ model to dispatch messages to consumers.". Also, my question was if the consumer is not gone but there is only an error in processing, would broker redelivery plugin deliver the msg to a different consumer or not ?

Comment: That's interesting ... you are absolutely right the prefetch makes the message to live in the client but until processing is done and ACK signal is received by the broker the message shall never be actually removed from the broker queue since that would open a hole to potential lose of messages. But you  are ritght there is something missing in my reasoning ... will dig around. thanks.